# Como faço em python para no final do codigo, ele ir para o inicio novamente

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook

Como faço em python para no final do codigo, ele ir para o inicio novamente e repetir uma vez a cada 3600 segundos?

Meu codigo:
*

```
fb     = Facebook ( "meu-token" )
fb.testing = False

try:
    start_time = time.time()
    markov.collecttext("./markov")
    #markov.collectjsons ("./markov")
    #markov.loadjson("data.json")
    #markov.savejson()
    train_time = time.time() - start_time

    start_time = time.time()
    generated = markov.generate (1)
    generation_time = time.time() - start_time

    if getpyversion() == 2:
        generated = generated.encode('utf8')

    image = randomimg("./images", generated)
    log("Chosen image: " + str(image))

    if not image:
        image = randomimg("./images")
        log("No tags found, randomly chosen image: " + str(image))
        message_start = "Este post foi gerado pelo Marcos Bot\n----------\n"
    else:
        log("tags: " + ", ".join(gettags(generated, image)))
        message_start = "The image was chosen because of the following tag(s): " + ", ".join(gettags(generated, image)) + "\n----------\n"

    response = fb.publish_image ( censor(generated), image )

    log(response)
except Exception as e:
    log("Failed to generate sentence. Posting a random image instead.")
    log(traceback.format_exc(e))
    message = "Failed to generate sent(i)ence. Posting a random image instead:"

    image = randomimg("./images")
    log("Chosen image: " + str(image))

    if not image:
        response = fb.publish_text ( message )
    else:
        response = fb.publish_image ( message, image )

    log(response)
```

main()*

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
def my_function():
  threading.Timer(3600, my_function).start()
  print("Hello, World!")

my_function()
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/thread1), coloquei 5 segundos para vc ver como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

cria um loop "while True:" assim o programa vai se repetir infinitamente, e é só implementar um flag no final para sair do loop e encerrar o programa.

Answer (score -2):

Outra opção (não só em python seria transformar isso em uma função recursiva, que chama a si mesmo ao final da execução...

Comment: Isso seria altamente custoso, praticamente inviável. :-(

Comment: Sim pode ser, mas não deixa de ser uma opção =]

Comment: Uma opção inviável. :-)